# Bug in Infix calculator based on linked lists

Tags: c

I'm writing an Infix calculator that performs operations like 5*(2+1). I have a bug in the code I cannot identify. I've written out a minimal code showing off the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct x{
    double value;
    char op;
    struct x *next;
};

void add_item(struct x **ptr, double data);
void multiply (struct x *head, struct x *end);
void add (struct x *head, struct x *end);
void calculate (struct x *head, struct x *end);
void del(struct x *head);

int main()
{
    struct x *head = NULL;
    struct x **end;

    add_item(&head, 5);
    head->op = '*';

    end = &head; /*I keep track of the node after which parenthesis are entered*/

    add_item(&head, 2);

    head->op = '+';

    add_item(&head, 1);

    calculate(head, *end); /*calculate operations within parenthesis: 2+1*/
    calculate(head, NULL); /* calculate the remaining operations 5*3 */

    printf("%lf", head->value); /*This should print the overall result 15 instead of 3*/
    free(head);

    return 0;
}

void add_item(struct x **ptr, double data)
{
        struct x *item = malloc(sizeof *item);

        item->value = data;
        item->next = *ptr;
        item->op = '?';
        *ptr = item;
}

void calculate (struct x *head, struct x *end)
{  
    multiply(head, end);
    add(head, end);
}

void multiply (struct x *head, struct x *end)
{
    double result;

    if (head == end)
        return;

    if (head->next != end) {
        if ((head->next)->op == '*') {
            result = (head->next)->value * head->value;
            head->value = result;
            del(head);
            multiply(head, end);
        }

        else
            add(head->next, end);
    }
}


void add (struct x *head, struct x *end)
{

    double result;

    if (head == end)
        return;

    if (head->next != end) {
        if ((head->next)->op == '+') {
            result = (head->next)->value + head->value;
            head->value = result;
            del(head);
            add(head, end);
        }

        else
            add(head->next, end);
    }
}

void del (struct x *before_del)
{
    struct x *temp;
    temp = before_del->next;
    before_del->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

The code generates a linked list like this: 1->2->5->NULL 
With the first call `calculate(head, *end);` the program can perform correctly the operation within parenthesis and get `3` as result. The list at this point should be 3->5->NULL.
 But `calculate(head, NULL);` that should perform `5*3` fails.
The `end` pointer to pointer acts as an indicator to the node after which parenthesis are located. In this example the node containing the vale `5`.
If I have the expression `1+1+2*(5*3)` then `end` should point to the node containing the value `2`.

Comment: "should be 3->5->NULL" but is not?

Comment: "perform 5*3 fails" How?

Comment: I think it is right like that. I'm deleting the node containing 2 after performing 2+1. The node head should contain 3 as value, at this point

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci Sorry, I just deleted the comment you responded to.  It's very strange to me that you are deleting the second node of the list rather than the first.  Also, since there's no realy need for `temp`, it is a bit confusing.

Comment: The problem is that when you go to multiply 3 * 5, you don't, because head->next == end

Comment: It seems odd that you invoke `multiply` when you want to add.  Instead of storing `op` as a char, define the struct with `op` as a function pointer and just call it.  That is `struct x { double value; void (*op)(struct x *,struct x *); struct x*next; };` . Then, instead of `head->op = '*'`, write `head->op = multiply` and instead of calling `calculate(head, end)`, call `head->next->op(head, end)`

Comment: If you change the type of `end` to `struct x *` and do `end = head`, your code seems to work.  By assiging `end = &head`, it always points to the top of the stack.

Comment: @WilliamPursell you correctly identified the issue. But I need that end = &head; to point at the node where parenthesis are located. After performing the 1st calculation `2+1` I need a way to set `end` to NULL. So that `if (head->next != end)` reads as  `if (head->next != NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

By writing `end = &head`, end always points to the top of the stack.  You meant to do `end = head` (with appropriate re-declaration of `end`.  Here's a few edits that seems to work: (I say "seems to", because although this printf 15, I really question the logic of that `end` pointer.  Making `add` and `multiply` recursive seems unlikely to work)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct x {
        double value;
        void (*op)(struct x *,struct x *);
        struct x *next;
};

void add_item(struct x **ptr, double data);
void multiply (struct x *head, struct x *end);
void add (struct x *head, struct x *end);
void del(struct x *head);

int
main(void)
{
        struct x *head = NULL;
        struct x *end;

        add_item(&head, 5);
        head->op = multiply;

        end = head;
        add_item(&head, 2);

        head->op = add;
        add_item(&head, 1);

        head->next->op(head, end); /*calculate operations within parenthesis: 2+1*/
        head->next->op(head, NULL); /* calculate the remaining operations 5*3 */

        printf("%lf\n", head->value); /*This should print the overall result 15 instead of 3*/
        free(head);

        return 0;
}

void add_item(struct x **ptr, double data)
{
        struct x *item = malloc(sizeof *item);

        item->value = data;
        item->next = *ptr;
        *ptr = item;
}


void multiply (struct x *head, struct x *end)
{
        double result;

        if (head == end)
                return;

        if (head->next != end) {
                result = (head->next)->value * head->value;
                head->value = result;
                del(head);
                multiply(head, end);
        }
}

void add (struct x *head, struct x *end)
{


        if (head == end)
                return;

        if (head->next != end) {
                head->value = (head->next)->value + head->value;
                del(head);
                add(head, end);
        }
}

void del (struct x *before_del)
{
        struct x *temp;
        temp = before_del->next;
        before_del->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
}
```

Comment: for that scope I could simply use `head`. As I've specified in the question `end` must point to different locations depending on the position of parenthesis. I need a way to set `end` as NULL so that with the 2nd call of calculate()  `if (head->next != end)` reads as `if (head->next != NULL)`

Comment: Then you need to pass the address of end to the functions.